# Where is Error Log in lighttpd?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, lighttpd, 500-error, logging

I'm new to lighttpd, I just switched from Apache. How can I find the error log by SSH ? I've been getting some 500 Internal Server errors I want to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the error log is in your config file, which is probably located at `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`.  Look for the `server.errorlog` line.

If it's still set to default, the log is probably at `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`.